# android webview showing two edit fields

Tags: android

[image]

I am using web view in my activity. I am using an url to load the page. 
The page contains text field which takes user-name and password as input from user.
When I click on nay of the field a corresponding small field is shown overlapping the other.

Here I am attaching image how it looks when i click password field..

can anybody tell me how to solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please upload the HTML and the Code which calls the WebView?

Comment: webview is loading tweeter link..

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate question: [Double text box showing on Android ICS Webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12834914/double-text-box-showing-on-android-ics-webview)

Looks like you just have to add

```
-webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only;
```

To your css for input fields.