# Double text box showing on Android ICS Webview

Tags: android, webview

I have this webview with a Form, when I clicked on a textbox to type, this is what's happening:

[image: Double Textbox]

I have this on my html form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML Basic 1.1//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-basic/xhtml-basic11.dtd">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
```

I'm using samsung galaxy tab 2, android ice cream sandwich. I have the same experience on honeycomb.

I tried adding:

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

on the container and/or the input element itself, but nothing worked.

Thanks for any ideas on how do I fix this!

EDIT:

My html:

```
        <td class='valign_top' style='width:30%; -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);'>
            <div class='cell_lbl'>P.O. Number:</div>
            <input type='text' name='po_number' id='po_number' style='width:100%;' />
        </td>
```

When I tried it in built in browser, IT'S FINE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try to apply this:

```
-webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
```

or this:

```
-webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color:#3072af;
```

to your input box elements.

Comment: thanks! it works but when keyboard shows, the field does not move up, it was covered by the soft keyboard...